Can't install ros-noetic-ros-navigation package
I am trying to install the package ros-noetic-ros-navigation, but when running
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-ros-navigation

I get:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-ros-navigation

I tried running sudo apt update, which didn't change anything.
I can't seem to find a solution for this anywhere.

Its ros-noetic-navigation.
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-navigation


When you cannot install the package you expect to be there, use apt search with just a fragment of the name to locate its exact name. You can grep by 'ros' to get less bulky output:
apt search navigation | grep ros

This lists various packages containing the keyword, and between them I see
ros-noetic-navigation/focal
ros-noetic-navigation-experimental/focal

that means you have likely misspelled the name.
Another answer also says the same, but I tried to provide methods for determining the package name when is not known with certainty.
